# INSERT IGNORE not working

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert into the table if the entire row does not exist in the table. My code is below:

```
$insert_sql="insert ignore into indexes(id,user_id,course_id,index) values
             ('','".$row2['user_id']."','".$course_id."','".$index."')";
mysqli_query($db,$insert_sql);
```

but it inserts the duplicate rows

Comment: You need `not exists`

Comment: You should have unique key constraint on columns on which you want to be unique.

Comment: @Code-Monk The first column (id) is unique, But i want to ignore only if the entire row is same as the one which is going to be inserted.

Comment: @RafeequeKP . . . Please edit your question with sample data and scenarios about what you want to happen with various inserts.

Comment: I edited the code, that inserts the duplicate entries

Answer (score 0):

`insert ignore` ignores all errors.  If you are trying to avoid duplicates, then I advise you to use `on duplicate key update`.  This only ignores the one error of duplicates.

It starts by defining the duplicate key:

```
 create unique index idx_indexes_col1_col2 on indexes(col1, col2)
```

(whatever you want to be unique).

Then an `insert` like:

```
insert into indexes(col1, col2, . . . )
    values (. . . )
    on duplicate key update col1 = values(col1);
```

The `col = values(col1)` doesn't really do anything -- the value doesn't change.  But it does prevent the one error.